# C#のコマンドプロンプトで外部出力せずにinput情報を除いた結果を取得するには？

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, command-line

以下に示したコードは.mp4ファイルの秒数を一括取得するコマンドです。
外部出力した場合は秒数のみ出力されます。

できれば外部出力せずそのまま出力を受取たいのですが、
秒数以外の情報(ファイルのinput情報)も取得されてしまいます。
外部出力と同じように秒数のみ取得するなら
どのような処理になるのでしょうか？

```
    string コマンド="for /F %a in ('dir /b *.mp4') do (ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 %a >> mp4sec.txt)"

    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ComSpec");
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + コマンド ;
    p.Start();

    //出力を読み取る
    string results = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

【環境】
windows10 64bit 
visual stadio Express 2015 for desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FORおよびDIRコマンドをC#で代替して1ファイルずつ`ffprobe.exe`を実行すればよいのでは。

```
// var dirName = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
foreach (var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(dirName, "*.mp4"))
{
    string コマンド = "ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 \"" + fileName + "\"";

    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ComSpec");
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + コマンド;
    p.Start();
    p.Start();

    //出力を読み取る
    string results = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
参考になります。
ファイル数が少ないときはこれでいこうと思います。

Answer (score 0):

蛇足ですが、Explorerのプロパティにも時間情報があります。この情報でよければAPIで取得できます。

```
static class PropertyStore {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct PROPERTYKEY {
        public Guid fmtid;
        public int pid;

        public static PROPERTYKEY FromName(string name) {
            PROPERTYKEY key;
            PSGetPropertyKeyFromName(name, out key);
            return key;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct PROPVARIANT {
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public long hVal;
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("886d8eeb-8cf2-4446-8d02-cdba1dbdcf99"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IPropertyStore {
        void GetCount(out int cProps);
        void GetAt(int iProp, out PROPERTYKEY pkey);
        void GetValue([In] ref PROPERTYKEY key, out PROPVARIANT pv);
        void SetValue([In] ref PROPERTYKEY key, [In] ref PROPVARIANT propvar);
        void Commit();
    }

    [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
    static extern void SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(string pszPath, IntPtr pbc, int flags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, out IPropertyStore ppv);
    [DllImport("Propsys.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
    static extern void PSGetPropertyKeyFromName(string pszString, out PROPERTYKEY pkey);

    static PROPERTYKEY durationKey = PROPERTYKEY.FromName("System.Media.Duration");
    public static TimeSpan GetDuration(string fullPath) {
        IPropertyStore ps;
        SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(fullPath, IntPtr.Zero, 0, typeof(IPropertyStore).GUID, out ps);
        PROPVARIANT durationValue;
        ps.GetValue(ref durationKey, out durationValue);
        return TimeSpan.FromTicks(durationValue.hVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: APIで取得できるとは思いませんでした。
ffmpegが使えないときはこちらを使おうと思います。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

> 秒数以外の情報(ファイルのinput情報)も取得されてしまいます。

何も考えずに for コマンドを使った場合、ループ内で実行されたコマンドが表示されます。これはC#を使わずコマンドプロンプトで for コマンドを実行した場合も同じです。

```
R:\>for /l %i in (1,1,3) do echo %i

R:\>echo 1
1

R:\>echo 2
2

R:\>echo 3
3
```

実行したコマンドを表示せず、その実行結果だけを表示したい場合、

- あらかじめ `ECHO OFF` コマンドを実行しておく
- コマンドの頭に `@` を付ける

といった方法があります。バッチファイルでよく使われますね。

```
R:\>for /l %i in (1,1,3) do @echo %i
1
2
3
```

今回のケースでもこれが使えます。

```
string コマンド="for /F %a in ('dir /b *.mp4') do @(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 %a)"
```